# forming a sentence with a long form possessive adjective and a descriptive adjective

Tags: gramática

Since both the **long form possessive adjective** (mío) and a **descriptive adjective** (linda) goes directly after the noun, as in

```
 Mi amiga linda está aquí.
```

and

```
 La amiga mía está aquí.
```

i am confused as to where to place the possessive and descriptive adjectives when they belong to the same sentence.

```
La amiga linda mía está aquí.
```

or

```
La amiga mía linda está aquí.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I use a slightly different example, which makes it easier for me to imagine using in realistic conversations.  This will show the same issue that you were illustrating.

> Vamos a usar el libro mío, que está en la cocina.
>
> Vamos a usar el libro clásico.

How to combine?  You're right to wonder how to accommodate two adjectives after the noun.  Answer: recast.  I can think of a few possible ways:

> Vamos a usar el libro clásico, el mío, que está en la cocina.
>
> Vamos a usar el libro mío, el clásico.  Está en la cocina.
>
> Vamos a usar mi libro clásico, que está en la cocina.
>
> Vamos a usar el libro mío, que está en la cocina.  Es el clásico.

[Note, Spanish has two verbs that both translate to "is": one that essentially provides a definition, "El libro **es azul**," and one that describes a dynamic, changeable quality, "El libro está mojado"  | *The book is wet.*  That's why I edited your question and changed "es" to "está."  You will get to this pretty soon, I think, in your studies.]